# Android deeplink could not be opened in Skype

Tags: android, deeplink

I have an app which handles Android applinks. When clicking link on Android in Gmail native app - my app opens, but when clicking in Skype or Facebook - the web site is opened instead of my app.

The link structure is: https://www.myhost.dk/applink/?data=data
Do Android apps such as Skype or Facebook not supporting deeplinking?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="www.myhost.dk"
        android:pathPrefix="/applink"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Skype opens all links in a web view by default. To change this behavior, you can navigate to `Settings -> Messaging` and disable the `Web links open in Skype` button on your android device (or anything similar, perhaps the settings can slightly vary on the devices).

I have not checked that out on Facebook but assume the behavior could be similar to Skype.

Comment: yes after disable Web links open in Skype working as expected

Comment: I have same issue on chrome (android) any idea, ty